# WindowLoaded Trigger not fired

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

In my GTM site, I need to fire a tag only after entire page completely loaded in my website which is SPA.

I have created on JavaScript variable:

[image]

And created Trigger:

[image]

And tagged this trigger to my tag. But tag is not firing.
Do I need to configure in a different way to fire a tag?

Comment: Title refers to Window Loaded, but your screenshots refer to DOM loaded. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly is wrong with your setup but this seems like re-inventing the wheel. You can use built-in triggers [DOM Ready or Window Loaded](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679319)

[image]

Comment: Initially I have used window loaded trigger, but it triggers before my control values loaded in my website. I have assigned some custom dimension value in my tag. I want to capture that value.

Comment: If one tag depends on an other, you can set up tag sequencing, to maintain order of execution.

Comment: I see, but I don't think your solution would work because gtmDom you reference in your variable configuration is the exactly  same DOM Ready built-in trigger. In your case I would suggest firing custom event when your load your control values. https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#events